# How to grab the children of an Object.keys(myEl) reference

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular

In the code below, I can get a reference to the text000 object, but I need to capture its child array as my target payload. Once I have a reference to the key, how can I capture its children?

Full object is below:

```
activeItem = [{"dnd":{"index":0,"active":true,"group":"common","label":"Text (000)","type":"text"},
"json":{"schema":{"properties":{"text000":{"title":"Text (000)","type":"string"}},"required":["text000"]},"layout":[{"key":"text000","description":"","floatLabel":"auto","validationMessages":{"required":"Required"}}]}}]
```

To grab a reference to the "text000" key I'm using:

```
const myEl = Object.keys(this.activeItem.json.schema.properties); // points to text000
```

I need to pull that key's contents/children > {"title":"Text (000)","type":"string"} out to use it as my target payload for this operation.

The text000 element is dynamic so I need its reference, which is why I'm using the Object.keys() method to point to it.

Feel free to school me on the proper names to use to refer to these elements. For example, not sure exactly how to reference > {"title":"Text (000)","type":"string"} with respect to the key text000. Is that the key's "children", "value", "contents" or what?

UPDATE:

```
console.log('TRY: ', this.activeItem.json.schema.properties[0]);
// Returns undefined

console.log('TRY2: ', this.activeItem.json.schema.properties);
// Returns {"text000":{"title":"Text (000)","type":"string"}}
```

I need something to return:

```
{"title":"Text (000)","type":"string"}
```

SOLUTION thanks @jaredgorski:

```
const properties = this.activeItem.json.schema.properties;

const propertiesKeys = Object.keys(properties);

const propertiesKeysFirstVal = Object.keys(properties)[0];

const logProperties = properties[propertiesKeysFirstVal];

console.log('PROPERTIES KEYS:', propertiesKeys);
console.log(
'VALUES OF FIRST PROPERTIES KEY:',
propertiesKeysFirstVal
);
console.log('RESULT:', logProperties);


PROPERTIES KEYS: ["text000"]
wrux-wrux-form-builder.js:1782 VALUES OF FIRST PROPERTIES KEY: text000
wrux-wrux-form-builder.js:1783 RESULT: {title: "Text (000)", type: "string"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remember that `activeItem` is an array. As long as you include the index (in this case the first index, which is [0]), you can access the `json` property (or key) and continue down the chain to retrieve the values in `text000`.

The other trick here is that you're wanting to access the first key in `properties`, but you don't know the name of that key yet. So what you need to do is actually make an array of the keys and then find out the name of the first key in that `properties` object. To do this, you can use `Object.keys()`, a method which turns the keys of an object into an array. Once you have the name of this key, you only need to use bracket notation on the `properties` object to find the value for this key. I'll show you how this works in the snippet below.

Here are some references so that you can learn more about how this works:

- [MDN page on the `Object.keys()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [Accessing JavaScript
  object properties: Bracket notation vs. Dot notation](https://codeburst.io/javascript-quickie-dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation-333641c0f781)

And here's the working example:

```js
const activeItem = [
  {
    "dnd": {
      "index": 0,
      "active": true,
      "group":"common",
      "label":"Text (000)",
      "type":"text",
      "icon":"text_fields",
      "fontSet":"material-icons",
      "class":""
    },
    "json": {
      "schema": {
        "properties": {
          "text000":{
            "title":"Text (000)",
            "type":"string"
          }
        },
        "required":["text000"]
      },
      "layout":[
        {
          "key":"text000",
          "description":"",
          "floatLabel":"auto",
          "validationMessages": {
            "required":"Required"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]

// This is the dirty looking version:

const logPropertiesDirty = activeItem[0].json.schema.properties[Object.keys(activeItem[0].json.schema.properties)[0]]

console.log("First, the dirty version where we don't save anything to variables. Everything is laid out here.")
console.log('WHAT WE DID:', 'activeItem[0].json.schema.properties[Object.keys(activeItem[0].json.schema.properties)[0]]')
console.log('RESULT:', logPropertiesDirty)


console.log('=================================================')

// This is the cleaner version, using variables to store things as we go:

const properties = activeItem[0].json.schema.properties;

const propertiesKeys = Object.keys(properties);

const propertiesKeysFirstVal = Object.keys(properties)[0];

const logPropertiesClean = properties[propertiesKeysFirstVal];

console.log('Now, the cleaner version. We save some values to variables to make things more readable.')
console.log('PROPERTIES OBJECT:', properties)
console.log('PROPERTIES KEYS:', propertiesKeys)
console.log('NAME OF FIRST PROPERTIES KEY:', propertiesKeysFirstVal)
console.log('RESULT:', logPropertiesClean)
```

Regarding what to call these things, I've always thought of Objects as generally consisting of "key-value pairs". Keys can also be called properties and values can also be called contents (I guess).

```
myObject = {
  key1: value1,
  property2: contentsOfProperty2
}
```

At the end of the day, clear communication is all that counts! So, whatever names you come up with (as long as they make reasonable sense), I'm sure people won't be jerks about it unless they feel like they have something to prove.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! I can't hardcode the text000 reference in the query. It will be dynamically generated so I won't know its value for any given array, only its index. It will always be the first-child of properties.

Comment: Ah good to know! In that case, as long as you know the index, you can use that (in this case `[0]` again). Let me edit my answer then.

Comment: I've updated my question with the results of console logs to help narrow down the solution. I'm on the cusp.

Comment: I ran into a slight snag because my brain was blocked but I've just updated my solution for you. You have to use `Object.keys()` to treat the keys of `...properties` as an array, read that key, and then use the name of that key in bracket notation to access the key of `properties` you're targeting. Does that make slight sense? lol

Comment: That did it. The only issue I had was that this,activeItem[0],json throws an error. I had to change it to this.activeItem.json. I've updated the question with the console.log results

Comment: Ah, interesting. The idea behind using `activeItem[0]` is that it appears that `activeItem` is set equal to an expression that begins with a bracket `[`, followed by a curly brace `{`. This tells me that `activeItem` is not just a normal object, but an array of objects. In order to access the first index of this array I included the `[0]`. If you have trouble with it again you can consider this, because accessing arrays is different from accessing objects. Anyway, if you see my updated solution, I copied and pasted your `activeItem` from the question and was able to retrieve the output.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [**Object.values**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) over `this.activeItem.json.schema.properties`:

> The Object.values() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

```js
const object1 = {
  a: 'somestring',
  b: 42,
  c: false
};
console.log(Object.values(object1));
// expected output: Array ["somestring", 42, false]
```

It is not supported across the map yet, but you should be able to load a [polyfill](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js) if you need it.